# mod_rewrite problem

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this rewrite rule to access profile.php?user=username with mysite.com/username..

Problem with this is that it ignores my css, even if I use the full URL and whats weird is that its the same if i go to the regular url, profile.php?user=username. But If i remove my htaccess file the css works.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) profile.php?user=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Whats the problem here? Thanks in advance :>

Answer (score 2):

You could use a condition to only fire your rule if the URL you are attempting to fetch doesn't resolve to a file or directory

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) profile.php?user=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This will stop a request for foo.css being rewritten as profile.php?user=foo.css

Answer (score 0):

Your rule will rewrite any request, even the request for your css file.

You will also need a RewriteCond like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) profile.php?user=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This will redirect only if there is no file that matches the request.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the request for the CSS file is a request too, and your rule is rewriting the request for `whatever.css` to `profile.php?user=whatever.css`